# C++: Recursive Max of Array Function

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

```
static int max(int arr[ ], int size) {
if (size == 1)
   return arr[0];
int maxOfRest = max(arr + 1, size - 1);
if (arr[0] > maxOfRest)
    return arr[0];
else
    return maxOfRest;
}
```

I do not understand how this function works. Recursive functions like these don't quite make sense to me.

Comment: Apparently, you are not the first one to face that situation. https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-phrase-in-order-to-understand-recursion-you-must-first-understand-recursion-mean-to-you

Comment: Can you be specific? What part do you not understand?

Comment: When I look at a recursive function I don't understand, I first look at what has to be true for the recursion to stop. Then I look at how the parameters change in each level of recursion. This usually gives me an idea of what the recursion is doing. Thinking the recursion out backwards is usually a lot easier to understand than solving it moving forwards, too.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to understand recursion, it helps to have lines of code that print key information at suitable points. For your function, I would suggest:

```
static int max(int arr[ ], int size) {

if (size == 1)
   return arr[0];

int maxOfRest = max(arr + 1, size - 1);

std::cout << "maxOfRest: " << maxOfRest << ", arr[0]: " << arr[0] << std::endl;

if (arr[0] > maxOfRest)
    return arr[0];
else
    return maxOfRest;
}
```

I have a feeling that will help you understand how this particular function works.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured out what the code does, but did not like the way it is done.

When you intend to find the maximum element in an array:

1. You check if the size of the array is one. If it is true, you would return the first element in the array `arr[0]` .
2. Else you would compare the first element of the array `arr[0]` with the greatest element in the rest of the array `maxOfRest` and return the greater numbers `arr[0]` and `maxOfRest`.

The recursion is used in finding the greatest value from the rest of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you call this with length size of the array, therefore the method compare each value for other:

> A: 5, 4, 3, 9, 2

so you call `max (A, 5);`

> max ({5, 4, 3, 9, 2}, 5)
>
> size !=1 -> maxOfRest = max({4, 3, 9, 2}, 4)
>
> size !=1 -> maxOfRest = max({3, 9, 2}, 3)
>
> size !=1 -> maxOfRest = max({9, 2}, 2)
>
> size !=1 -> maxOfRest = max({2}, 1)

now, it's return 2 and we in the `if` condition and any time check if A[0] (next value) is bigger than maxOrRest:

> (9 > 2 ?
>
> 9 > 3 ?
>
> 9 > 4 ?
>
> return 9.)